# Ivy/gant include BlazeDS jars that aren`t in a public repo and have no version

Tags: blazeds, ivy, gant

I`ve been trying to figure out the best way to include the BlazeDS jars in my Gant/Ivy build.
I`ve been unable to find a public repo for these jars and I`m new to ivy. Obviously with Maven you`d just do a local maven install to your local repo. Whats the best way to do something similar with Ivy? Do I have to create a separate Ivy.xml file for each jar and then use Ivy Publish or is their another way?

Also does anyone know a public repo where the BlazeDS Jars are available

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered if you use Spring BlazeDS Inetgration project and include its dependency in ivy it`ll pull in the Flex jars from Spring Bundle repository.